# undefined reference to symbol '__cxa_pure_virtual@@CXXABI_1.3'

Tags: compiling, make

I'm faced with the following error when I run make for the files from https://github.com/liuliu/ccv

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/liblinear.a(linear-static.o): 
undefined reference to symbol '__cxa_pure_virtual@@CXXABI_1.3'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: 
error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My makefile is as follows:

```
include ../lib/config.mk
# CC += -g -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer # -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
LDFLAGS := -L"../lib" -lccv $(LDFLAGS)
CFLAGS := -O3 -Wall -I"../lib" $(CFLAGS)

TARGETS = bbffmt msermatch siftmatch bbfcreate bbfdetect scdcreate scddetect 
swtcreate swtdetect dpmdetect tld icfcreate icfdetect icfoptimize cifar-10 
image-net cnnclassify aflw dpmcreate

all: libccv.a $(TARGETS)

clean:
${MAKE} clean -C ../lib ; rm -f *.o $(TARGETS)

$(TARGETS): %: %.o libccv.a
$(CC) -o $@ $< $(LDFLAGS)

libccv.a:
${MAKE} -C ../lib

%.o: %.c ../lib/ccv.h
$(CC) $< -o $@ -c $(CFLAGS)
```

And the config.mk is as follows:

```
CC := clang
AR := ar
NVCC := 
CUDA_OBJS := 
DEFINE_MACROS := -D HAVE_LIBPNG -D HAVE_LIBJPEG -D HAVE_FFTW3 -D HAVE_LIBLINEAR 
-D HAVE_TESSERACT -D HAVE_AVCODEC -D HAVE_AVFORMAT -D HAVE_SWSCALE -D
USE_DISPATCH -D HAVE_SSE2 -D HAVE_GSL
prefix := /usr/local
exec_prefix := ${prefix}
CFLAGS := -fblocks -msse2 $(DEFINE_MACROS) -I${prefix}/include
NVFLAGS := --use_fast_math -arch=sm_30 $(DEFINE_MACROS)
LDFLAGS := -L${exec_prefix}/lib -lm -lpng -ljpeg -lfftw3 -lfftw3f -lpthread -llinear 
-ltesseract -lavcodec -lavformat -lswscale -ldispatch -lBlocksRuntime -lgsl 
-lgslcblas
```

I've tried seeking help from the developer(was helpful with most queries), read through the make file tutorials and search similar problems but still don't understand what needs to be done.

Please help.

Comment: Maybe you should move this question to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) as this has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: Ok, sounds like a good idea. Thank you. I'll try that.

Comment: I don't use `clang` but whenever you see errors about missing symbols from `libstdc++.so.6` a good place to start would be to check you are not trying to build C++  with a C compiler - perhaps you should be setting `CC := clang++`?